# I would like to know the exact steps to use SHPAML in django 1.8 +

Tags: python, django, shpaml

I have been going through the installation instruction on their home page and github page. I installed the 1.3.0 version and well as added the following code in settings.py.

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ('shpaml.Loader',
        ('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',)
    ),
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)  

if not DEBUG:
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
        ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', TEMPLATE_LOADERS),
    )
```

But even when I end the files .shpaml, the shpaml code is executed as simple text.

I would like to know where to place the code exactly as well as what to do to make it work.

Comment: Note that the template engine was upgraded/changed in django 1.7. Those settings are no longer relevant. See this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#configuration You might have to change settings according to this.

Comment: It appears that SHPAML is actually not compatible with Django 1.8+. Is there a specific reason you need this? In almost all cases, the built-in Django template engine should be used, unless there is a very specific need for a different one.